# FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. (For Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, firebase, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I followed this link to create a fire base application-https://blog.mestwin.net/send-push-notifications-from-spring-boot-server-side-application-using-fcm/
And I am getting this error-FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. (For Spring Boot)
I have added the JSON Key and and its path in application properties....Am not able to figure out where I Am going wrong...
This is my FCMInitializer-

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.IOException;



@Service
public class FCMInitializer {



    @Value("${app.firebase-configuration-file}")
    private String firebaseConfigPath;

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FCMInitializer.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        try {
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new ClassPathResource(firebaseConfigPath).getInputStream())).build();
            if (FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
                FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
                logger.info("Firebase application has been initialized");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

This is my FCM Service-

```
import com.google.firebase.messaging.*;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

//import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
//import com.highpeak.av.pushnotification.dto.PushNotificationRequest;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class FCMService {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FCMService.class);

    public void sendMessage(Map<String, String> data, PushNotificationRequest request)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Message message = getPreconfiguredMessageWithData(data, request);
        String response = sendAndGetResponse(message);
        log.info("Sent message with data. Topic: " + request.getTopic() + ", " + response);
    }

    private Message getPreconfiguredMessageWithData(Map<String, String> data, PushNotificationRequest request) {
        return getPreconfiguredMessageBuilder(request).putAllData(data).setTopic(request.getTopic())
                .build();
    }



    public void sendMessageWithoutData(PushNotificationRequest request)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Message message = getPreconfiguredMessageWithoutData(request);
        String response = sendAndGetResponse(message);
        log.info("Sent message without data. Topic: " + request.getTopic() + ", " + response);
    }



    private String sendAndGetResponse(Message message) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        return FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendAsync(message).get();
    }

    private AndroidConfig getAndroidConfig(String topic) {
        return AndroidConfig.builder()
                .setTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(2).toMillis()).setCollapseKey(topic)
                .setPriority(AndroidConfig.Priority.HIGH)
                .setNotification(AndroidNotification.builder().setSound(NotificationParameter.SOUND.getValue())
                        .setColor(NotificationParameter.COLOR.getValue()).setTag(topic).build()).build();
    }

    private ApnsConfig getApnsConfig(String topic) {
        return ApnsConfig.builder()
                .setAps(Aps.builder().setCategory(topic).setThreadId(topic).build()).build();
    }

    private Message getPreconfiguredMessageWithoutData(PushNotificationRequest request) {
        return getPreconfiguredMessageBuilder(request).setTopic(request.getTopic())
                .build();
    }



    private Message.Builder getPreconfiguredMessageBuilder(PushNotificationRequest request) {
        AndroidConfig androidConfig = getAndroidConfig(request.getTopic());
        ApnsConfig apnsConfig = getApnsConfig(request.getTopic());
        return Message.builder()
                .setApnsConfig(apnsConfig).setAndroidConfig(androidConfig).setNotification(
                        new Notification(request.getTitle(), request.getMessage()));
    }


    public void sendMessageToToken(PushNotificationRequest request)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Message message = getPreconfiguredMessageToToken(request);
        String response = sendAndGetResponse(message);
        log.info("Sent message to token. Device token: " + request.getToken() + ", " + response);
    }


    private Message getPreconfiguredMessageToToken(PushNotificationRequest request) {
        return getPreconfiguredMessageBuilder(request).setToken(request.getToken())
                .build();
    }



}
```

This is my PushNotification Service-

```
package com.example.MyFirstPushNotificationService.PushNotificationsDemo;

import com.google.api.client.util.Value;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

@Service
public class PushNotificationService {

    @Value("#{${app.notifications.defaults}}")
    private Map<String, String> defaults;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PushNotificationService.class);
    private FCMService fcmService;

    public PushNotificationService(FCMService fcmService) {
        this.fcmService = fcmService;
    }

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 60000, fixedDelay = 60000)
    public void sendSamplePushNotification() {
        try {
            fcmService.sendMessageWithoutData(getSamplePushNotificationRequest());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void sendPushNotification(PushNotificationRequest request) {
        try {
            fcmService.sendMessage(getSamplePayloadData(), request);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void sendPushNotificationWithoutData(PushNotificationRequest request) {
        try {
            fcmService.sendMessageWithoutData(request);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public void sendPushNotificationToToken(PushNotificationRequest request) {
        try {
            fcmService.sendMessageToToken(request);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private Map<String, String> getSamplePayloadData() {
        Map<String, String> pushData = new HashMap<>();
        pushData.put("messageId", defaults.get("payloadMessageId"));
        pushData.put("text", defaults.get("payloadData") + " " + LocalDateTime.now());
        return pushData;
    }


    private PushNotificationRequest getSamplePushNotificationRequest() {
        PushNotificationRequest request = new PushNotificationRequest(defaults.get("title"),
                defaults.get("message"),
                defaults.get("topic"));
        return request;
    }


}
```

This is my PushNotificationController-

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class PushNotificationController {

    private PushNotificationService pushNotificationService;

    public PushNotificationController(PushNotificationService pushNotificationService) {
        this.pushNotificationService = pushNotificationService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/notification/topic")
    public ResponseEntity sendNotification(@RequestBody PushNotificationRequest request) {
        pushNotificationService.sendPushNotificationWithoutData(request);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new PushNotificationResponse(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Notification has been sent."), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/notification/token")
    public ResponseEntity sendTokenNotification(@RequestBody PushNotificationRequest request) {
        pushNotificationService.sendPushNotificationToToken(request);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new PushNotificationResponse(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Notification has been sent."), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/notification/data")
    public ResponseEntity sendDataNotification(@RequestBody PushNotificationRequest request) {
        pushNotificationService.sendPushNotification(request);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new PushNotificationResponse(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Notification has been sent."), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/notification")
    public ResponseEntity sendSampleNotification() {
        pushNotificationService.sendSamplePushNotification();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new PushNotificationResponse(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Notification has been sent."), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

This is my Notification Parameter-

```
public enum NotificationParameter {
    SOUND("default"),
    COLOR("#FFFF00");

    private String value;

    NotificationParameter(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

This is my PushNotificationRequest-

```
public class PushNotificationRequest {

    private String title;
    private String message;
    private String topic;
    private String token;

    public PushNotificationRequest() {
    }

    public PushNotificationRequest(String title, String messageBody, String topicName) {
        this.title = title;
        this.message = messageBody;
        this.topic = topicName;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getTopic() {
        return topic;
    }

    public void setTopic(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
}
```

This is my push notification Response-

```
package com.example.MyFirstPushNotificationService.PushNotificationsDemo;

public class PushNotificationResponse {

    private int status;
    private String message;

    public PushNotificationResponse() {
    }

    public PushNotificationResponse(int status, String message) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

And this is my application-properties:

```
app.firebase-configuration-file=google/push-notifications-example-firebase-adminsdk.json
app.notifications.defaults={topic: 'common', title: 'Common topic - Hello', message: 'Sending test message \uD83D\uDE42', token: 'ss22t03wz208eg:APA2idkkow223FE_0v5yHxqCLTyxAQafj6nWaqi4QzwZTW004q1PUux63UsFN', payloadMessageId: '123', payloadData: 'Hello. This is payload content.'}
```

Please forgive me,as i am still a beginner in Fire base.....I am not getting where I am gong wrong....I think its in application properties.....Also I am getting the error at-FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendAsync(message).get();  of FCMService class.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5):

I was having same error, try debugging initialize() method in FCMInitializer.java, in my case it was having wrong JSON file path, after providing correct path, issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I hope to arrive on time, I had the same problem and my solution was to put the authentication that the firebase console suggests.

@Service
public class FCMInitializer {

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FCMInitializer.class);

   @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        try {
            FileInputStream serviceAccount =
                      new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

                    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                      .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                      .setDatabaseUrl("https://your-project.firebaseio.com")
                      .build();

                    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tlb6O.png)

Answer (score 1):

Add `@DependsOn("fCMInitializer")` to services that depend on Firebase.
Example:

```
@Service
@DependsOn("fCMInitializer")
public class PushNotificationService
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the file path to the Firebase SDK Admin JSON file.

To fix the error the location of the JSON file should have been `target/classes/<File name here>.json` as this is the canonical place where Maven puts resource files after processing.